# Geoserver not processing the data from drupal

Tags: geoserver, drupal

I am using drupal cms to render the maps. I am using geoserver since I need to render more than say 50000 points.  I am following the tutorial given in http://drupal.org/node/845852. I am getting stuck up as geoserver is able to read the values present in drupal database through `http://localhost/drupal6/wfspath?request=GetCapabilities` but unable to process them, I came to this conclusion because I am not able to see the  point image in layer preview->openlayers and the layer preview->GML file is blank........... I am attaching.

wfs_data.png - gml at drupal(http://localhost/drupal6/wfspath)

wfs_GetCapabilities.png - `http://localhost/drupal6/wfspath?request=GetCapabilities` given in geoserver store

test_gml.png - geoserver->layer preview->gml

test_OL.png - geoserver->layer preview->openlayers

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

This is my Log file but I cannot understand the error

```
2011-05-10 04:03:16,599 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - filtering http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms
2011-05-10 04:03:16,602 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
2011-05-10 04:03:16,603 DEBUG [geotools.styling] - number of fts set 1
2011-05-10 04:03:16,603 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - establishing point style for testws:drupal_testwfsview
2011-05-10 04:03:16,607 DEBUG [wms.responses] - setting up map
2011-05-10 04:03:16,624 DEBUG [wms.responses] - asking delegate for write to org.geoserver.ows.DispatcherOutputStream@12e1a27
2011-05-10 04:03:16,918 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - filtering http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms
2011-05-10 04:03:16,923 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
2011-05-10 04:03:16,924 DEBUG [geotools.styling] - number of fts set 1
2011-05-10 04:03:16,924 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - establishing point style for testws:drupal_testwfsview
2011-05-10 04:03:16,927 DEBUG [wms.responses] - setting up map
2011-05-10 04:03:16,932 DEBUG [wms.map] - setting up 660x330 image
2011-05-10 04:03:16,932 DEBUG [geotools.styling] - number of fts set 1
2011-05-10 04:03:16,934 DEBUG [renderer.shape] - Affine Transform is AffineTransform[[1.422222222222222, 0.0, 330.0], [0.0, -1.422222222222222, 165.0]]
2011-05-10 04:03:16,935 DEBUG [geotools.rendering] - Computed scale denominator: 2.795411320143589E8
2011-05-10 04:03:16,936 DEBUG [geotools.styling] - number of fts set 1
2011-05-10 04:03:16,936 DEBUG [geotools.rendering] - processing 1 stylers for http://drupal.org/project/wfs:drupal_testwfsview
2011-05-10 04:03:16,936 DEBUG [geotools.rendering] - creating rules for scale denominator - 279,541,132.014
2011-05-10 04:03:16,937 DEBUG [geotools.rendering] - Expanding rendering area by 6 pixels to consider stroke width
2011-05-10 04:03:16,937 DEBUG [geotools.rendering] - Querying layer drupal_testwfsview with bbox: ReferencedEnvelope[-236.25 : 236.25, -120.234375 : 120.234375]
2011-05-10 04:03:16,945 WARN [data.wfs] - Query does not provide a CRS, using default: Query: [liteRenderer]
   feature type: drupal:testwfsview
   filter: org.geotools.renderer.lite.FastBBOX@3bb53f
   [properties: geometry]
2011-05-10 04:03:16,955 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - [ class org.geotools.geometry.DirectPosition2D ] is not of type class [Ljava.lang.Double;
2011-05-10 04:03:16,956 DEBUG [geotools.xml] - [ class org.geotools.geometry.DirectPosition2D ] is not of type class [Ljava.lang.Double;
2011-05-10 04:03:17,588 DEBUG [data.wfs] - response head: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><wfs:FeatureCollection
   xmlns:drupal="http://drupal.org/project/wfs"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsi="http:/

2011-05-10 04:03:17,593 DEBUG [geotools.rendering] - Style cache hit ratio: NaN , hits 0, requests 0
2011-05-10 04:03:17,593 DEBUG [renderer.shape] - Style cache hit ratio: NaN , hits 0, requests 0
2011-05-10 04:03:17,593 DEBUG [wms.responses] - asking delegate for write to org.geoserver.ows.DispatcherOutputStream@9d6ff7
2011-05-10 04:03:17,594 DEBUG [map.png] - Writing png image ...
2011-05-10 04:03:17,594 DEBUG [geotools.image] - Encoded input image for png writer
2011-05-10 04:03:17,594 DEBUG [geotools.image] - Getting a writer
2011-05-10 04:03:17,595 DEBUG [geotools.image] - Setting write parameters for this writer
2011-05-10 04:03:17,595 DEBUG [geotools.image] - Writer is NOT native
2011-05-10 04:03:17,596 DEBUG [geotools.image] - About to write png image
2011-05-10 04:03:17,639 DEBUG [map.png] - Writing png image ... done!
2011-05-10 04:03:18,222 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - filtering http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows
2011-05-10 04:03:18,224 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2011-05-10 04:03:18,241 DEBUG [geoserver.requests] - Query is net.opengis.wfs.impl.QueryTypeImpl@19c9b66 (group: [], propertyName: [], function: null, filter: null, sortBy: [], featureVersion: null, handle: null, srsName: null, typeName: [{http://drupal.org/project/wfs}drupal_testwfsview])
 To gt2: Query:
   feature type: drupal_testwfsview
   filter: Filter.INCLUDE
   [properties:  ALL ]
2011-05-10 04:03:18,242 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    handle = null
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    providedVersion = null
    query = [net.opengis.wfs.impl.QueryTypeImpl@19c9b66 (group: null, propertyName: null, function: null, filter: null, sortBy: null, featureVersion: null, handle: null, srsName: null, typeName: [{http://drupal.org/project/wfs}drupal_testwfsview])]
    maxFeatures = 50
    outputFormat = GML2
    resultType = results
    traverseXlinkDepth = null
    traverseXlinkExpiry = null
    formatOptions = {}
2011-05-10 04:03:18,254 WARN [data.wfs] - Query does not provide a CRS, using default: Query:
   feature type: drupal:testwfsview
   filter: Filter.INCLUDE
   [properties: geometry, body, nid, title]
2011-05-10 04:03:18,892 DEBUG [data.wfs] - response head: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><wfs:FeatureCollection
   xmlns:drupal="http://drupal.org/project/wfs"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsi="http:/

2011-05-10 04:03:18,896 DEBUG [geotools.gml] - closing reader org.geotools.feature.collection.DelegateFeatureIterator@17c555d
2011-05-10 04:03:23,541 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - filtering http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/
2011-05-10 04:03:23,557 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.0.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.0.3.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/screen.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2011-05-10 04:03:23,564 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.0.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.0.3.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/print.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2011-05-10 04:03:23,567 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.0.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.0.3.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/geoserver.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2011-05-10 04:03:23,571 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.0.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.0.3.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/blueprint/ie.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2011-05-10 04:03:23,578 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.0.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.0.3.jar!/org/geoserver/web/css/geoserver-ie.css to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2011-05-10 04:03:23,584 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.0.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.0.3.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
2011-05-10 04:03:23,596 DEBUG [geoserver.web] - cannot convert url: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.0.3/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/web-core-2.0.3.jar!/org/geoserver/web/js/jquery.inline-info.js to file (URI is not hierarchical), falling back to the inputstream for polling
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default geoserver is mapping wfs request on
   http://yourserver:port/geoserver/wms. However you seem to map it to http://localhost/drupal6/wfspath.

I think that if you copy the parameters after the ? in the openlayers request and put it after http://localhost/drupal6/wfspath?  you will get the data out

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the style for the layer is misconfigured in some way. Trying doing a WMS capabilities, it will often tell you if this is the case:

/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities

You should also look at the geoserver log, there might be some other error occuring and if so it will show up there.